# Spring Jpa save() deletes columns from child entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

CandRef.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@IdClass(CandRefKey.class)
@Table(name = "EDJ_CANDD_REF")
public class CandRef implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -7171464769202238804L;

@Id
@Column(name = "EDJ_CANDD_ID")
private Integer candId;

@Id
@Column(name = "EDJ_CANDD_INST_NO")
private Integer instNo;

@Id
@Column(name = "SEQ_NO")
private Integer seqNo;

@Column(name = "EFF_BEG_DA")
private LocalDate beginDate;

@Column(name = "EFF_END_DA")
private LocalDate endDate;

@Column(name = "EDJ_RQSTN_ID")
private Integer rqstnId;

@Column(name = "RCRT_STAT_CD")
private String statCd;

@Column(name = "RCRT_STAT_DA")
private LocalDate startDate;

@Column(name = "CANDD_ORG_CD")
private String orgCd;

@Column(name = "CANDD_ORG_TYPE_CD")
private String orgTypeCd;

@Column(name = "ISO_CTRY_CD")
private String ctryCd;

@Column(name = "REF_GRP_ID")
private Integer refGrpId;

@OneToMany
@JoinTable(name = "REF_GRP_MBER", joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "REF_GRP_ID", referencedColumnName = "REF_GRP_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "REF_MBER_ID", referencedColumnName = "REF_MBER_ID") })
private Set<Member> members;

@Column(name = "REF_CNT_IND")
private String cntInd;

@Column(name = "REF_CR_IND")
private String creditInd;

@Column(name = "EDJ_CANDD_TY_CD")
private String candTyCd;

@Column(name = "REF_EXC_TY_CD")
private String excTyCd;

@Column(name = "REF_EXC_REVW_STAT_CD")
private String revwStatCd;
}
```

GrpMember.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Entity
@IdClass(GrpMemberKey.class)
@Table(name = "REF_GRP_MBER")
public class GrpMember implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -6907938568490379028L;

@Id
@Column(name = "REF_GRP_ID")
private String refGrpId;

@Id
@Column(name = "REF_MBER_ID")
private Integer refMemberId;

@Column(name = "REF_CR_QTY")
private Double creditQty;

@CreationTimestamp
@Column(name = "CRE_TS", nullable = false, updatable= false)
private LocalDateTime createTimeStamp;

@Column(name = "CRE_PGM_NA", nullable = false, updatable= false)
private String createPrgmName;

@Column(name = "CRE_UID_CD", nullable = false, updatable= false)
private String createUIDCD;

@UpdateTimestamp
@Column(name = "REVSN_TS", nullable = false, insertable= false)
private LocalDateTime revisonTimeStamp;

@Column(name = "REVSN_PGM_NA", nullable = false, insertable= false)
private String revisonPrgmName ="RC_SVC";

@Column(name = "REVSN_UID_CD", nullable = false, insertable= false)
private String revisonUIDCD ="ATSWEB";
}
```

Member.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Entity
@Table(name = "REF_MBER")
public class Member {

@Id
@Column(name = "REF_MBER_ID")
private Integer refMemberId;

@Column(name = "EFF_BEG_DA")
private LocalDate beginDate;

@Column(name = "EFF_END_DA")
private LocalDate endDate;

@Column(name = "REF_EDJ_PRSN_ID")
private String refPrsnId;

@Column(name = "REF_LOC_CD")
private String refLocCd;

@Column(name = "EDJ_PRSN_GROUP_CD")
private String prsnGrpCd;

@Column(name = "REF_ORG_CD")
private String orgCd;

@Column(name = "REF_ORG_TYPE_CD")
private String orgTypeCd;

@Column(name = "ORG_ONLY_REF_IND")
private String orgRefInd;

@Formula("(SELECT g.REF_CR_QTY FROM REF_GRP_MBER g WHERE g.ref_mber_id = REF_MBER_ID)")
private Double creditQty;

@CreationTimestamp
@Column(name = "CRE_TS")
private LocalDateTime createTimeStamp;

@Column(name = "CRE_PGM_NA")
private String createPrgmName;

@Column(name = "CRE_UID_CD")
private String createUIDCD;

@UpdateTimestamp
@Column(name = "REVSN_TS")
private LocalDateTime revisonTimeStamp;

@Column(name = "REVSN_PGM_NA")
private String revisonPrgmName;

@Column(name = "REVSN_UID_CD")
private String revisonUIDCD;
}
```

CandRefRepository.java

```
public interface CandidateRefRepository extends CrudRepository<CandRef, CandRefKey> {

List<CandRef> findByCandIdOrderByInstNoDesc(Integer candId);

List<CandRef> findAllByCandIdAndStatCd(Integer candId, String statCd);

@Query(value = CandidateRefConstants.CURRENT_INSTANCE_WITH_EXCEPTION)
List<CandRef> fetchCurrentInstance();

@Query(value = CandidateRefConstants.CURRENT_MAX_SEQUENCE_BY_CANDID)
CandRef fetchCurrentMaxSequence(@Param("candId") Integer candId);

@Query(value = CandidateRefConstants.CURRENT_INSTANCE_BY_STATCD)
List<CandRef> fetchCurrentInstanceBycandId(@Param("candId") Integer candId);

}
```

I am using spring boot and spring jpa with hibernate to save or update the CandRef entity using save() method.
The save method calls delete on the "REF_GRP_MBER" table after an update on "EDJ_CANDD_REF" table. Now in this case, the **private Set members** is always **null** and I am unable to understand why it is trying to delete a column from child table.

I do not want to delete/update any of the columns in either of child tables. I did try **insertable = false, updatable = false** on the jointable which did not work

Can someone please help me out here?

Thanks in advance.

```
delete 
from
    ref_grp_mber 
where
    ref_grp_id=?
```

Comment: You'd need to add then code where you modify or create the entities.

Comment: I just use save(candRef) method of the Spring jpa repository.

Comment: I'm aware of that. That is not what I suggested you should post.

Answer (score 0):

And what exactly do you change when this happens? If members change, then this is a logical behavior, because table REF_GRP_MBER stores relations with members and if they change, the old record is deleted and a new one is added in accordance with the changes

Comment: True, members is **null** at this point so hibernate thinks it should be deleted. But how would i prevent this behavior? I tried updatable = false in the joincolumn